# Oracle SQL | Use regex to ignore control characters except new line?

Tags: oracle

I need to identify and replace all the control characters in a column with ''
I tried using following query.

```
 SELECT description, REGEXP_REPLACE(description, '[![:cntrl:]]', '') from table1;
```

It removes all the control characters along with the new line character. I need to sustain the new line character. I tried using something like following.

```
 REGEXP_REPLACE(description, '[![:cntrl:]'||CHR(10)||CHR(13)||']', '')
```

But it didn't work. I would appreciate any help in right direction.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share more information or the sample data vs expected data ?

Answer (score 4):

`:cntrl:` is the opposite of `:print:`, so you could negate the combination of that plus the control character(s) you want to keep:

```
regexp_replace(description, '[^[:print:]'||chr(10)||']', null)
```

or possibly, based on your attempt (but not needed if you did only mean 'new line'):

```
regexp_replace(description, '[^[:print:]'||chr(10)||chr(13)||']', null)
```

The negation is done by `^`, not `!`. Your original code was removing any control characters or the actual character `!`, which probably wasn't quite what you meant.